# Are there photosensitive/light-sensitive glasses that use visible light to expose an image?

Tags: visible-light, glass

For instance, im wondering if there were a glass I could expose an image using an enlarger, and fix the glass without using heat.
I doubt it, just curious to know if UV exposed, heat-cured photosensitive glasses are the only type.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post. Let me know if there is a better place. (tried chemistry and photography already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are photopolymers that can store an image when exposed to visible light.  If you need glass specifically, I suspect it's possible but only know for sure that there are UV sensitive glasses.  With sufficient intensity, visible light can induce damage in many kinds of glass.- e.g., a femtosecond laser can do it.

Comment: Hey thanks, great answer. Which types of photopolymers are these? A bubblegram is probably the modern accessible method, correct?  Still, I am curious about glass...but if it did exist it's probably out of reach/not accessible for use.

Comment: My experience is with holographic photopolymers.  Bayer sells a holographic photopolymer film but only in big quantities.  Dupont has a film, but won't sell it; will only manufacture holographic optical elements from it.

Comment: It will be a challenge.  There are ways to coat photographic emulsions on non- flat surfaces, which might serve your purpose: coat on the inside of the sphere so the outside surface is glass.  Note, though, that you don't need visible light.  You just need to form a visible image.